# Solr error in entity query with double-quotes

Tags: solr, double-quotes

I have connected my oracle schema to solr. The tables and columns in my oracle schema were created with double-quotes(") and I am getting errors when using them below in the entity query portion of dataconfig.xml:

```
<entity name="itemsum" query="select * from Bug b where b."item" = 8 " >
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Element type "entity" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

I know it is because of the double-quote but I cannot recreate my table and columns. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: use `&quot; ` instead of "" because of xml issues

Answer (score 0):

Did you try escaping the quotes with a '\' ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quotes to surround attribute values in XML:

```
<entity name="itemsum" query='select * from Bug b where b."item" = 8 ' >
```

Alternatively, you can escape the quote characters as &quot;

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape those characters... you can use [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) to see how to escape chars in xml.. that should help